# What's wrong with the icons from Summernote ? I cannot see them

Tags: javascript, php, laravel

For Your Information, my project was built with Framework Laravel 5.2 and I used Summernote as WYSIWYG Text Editor on my project...

The problem is... i can't see the icons for the text editor...
This is the script:

```
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/summernote.js"> </script>
  <script>
          $(document).ready(function() {
          $('#summernote').summernote({
          height: 300,
          minHeight:null,
          maxHeight:null,
          focus:true
          });
    });
   </script>
```

...and this is the ID on php...

```
 @extends('layouts.app')
 @section('content')
 <div class="container">
 <div id="summernote">

 </div>
 </div>

 @endsection
```

Comment: Check your console if you get some 404 for not found resources like CSS, images , fonts, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Just use font awesome before you use your summernote css.

You can use CDN :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css">
```